# Trying to do a POST request from node.js to Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, node.js

I'm trying to do a POST request with some data to my Django script. It's just something for internal use so security isn't an issue, but it doesn't seem to want to print anything. It prints "TEST", so I know the post request is being received properly, but according to the Django docs, `HttpRequest.POST` should print a dictionary of the POST data.

Django

```
 @csrf_exempt
    def botdeposit(request):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            print(HttpRequest.GET)
            return redirect('/')
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            print('TEST')
            print(HttpRequest.POST)
            return redirect('/')
```

node.js

```
var request = require('request');

// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
    'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    form: {'key1': 'xxx', 'key2': 'yyy'}
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Print out the response body
        console.log(body)
    }
    console.log(body);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.POST` will. `HttpRequest` is a class, and you have its instance. Just like docs say `HttpRequest.method` is a thing, but you write `request.method`.

(Yes, the docs are confusing, and not showing well the difference between class and instance values.)

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure I understand your answer. I want to get the form values passed through, how could I do that? Thanks for responding.

Comment: Literally, replace `print(HttpRequest.POST)` with `print(request.POST)`. (Same for `GET`, obviously,)